# Connecting 2 different statefulSets to the same PV

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

I have a statefulSet that has a VolumeClaim.

The volume section of **StatefulSet1** is

```
  volumes:
  - name: artifact
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: artifacts
```

The PVC definition is

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: artifacts
spec:
  accessModes:
    - "ReadWriteOnce"
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: "5Gi"
  storageClassName: default
```

Now when I spin up StatefulSet1, everything is ok. The pod get the claim and is successfully mounted.

Now I want to bring up another Stateful set i.e. StatefulSet2 which needs to attach to the PV.

So my volume section of **StatefulSet2** is the same.

```
  volumes:
  - name: artifact
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: artifacts
```

But when I spin up StatefulSet2, my original PVC goes into terminating state.

```
kubectl get pvc artifacts
NAME                STATUS        VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
artifacts           Terminating   pvc-b55f729d-e115-11e8-953e-02000a1bef39   5Gi       RWO            rbd-mario      31m
```

And the new pod is continuously in Pending state.

Not sure what Im doing wrong here. But my aim is to connect multiple StatefulSets/Pods to the same PV.

Comment: https://docs.okd.io/latest/install_config/storage_examples/shared_storage.html

Answer (score 1):

> The **accessMode** for this PVC is set to **ReadWriteMany** so the kubernetes
>   allows mounting this PVC on multiple pods

https://docs.portworx.com/scheduler/kubernetes/shared-volumes.html

https://docs.okd.io/latest/install_config/storage_examples/shared_storage.html

More likely this should work:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: artifacts
spec:
  accessModes:
    - "ReadWriteMany"
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: "5Gi"
  storageClassName: default
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have that option. A describe on the PVC states `Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "rbd-mario": invalid AccessModes [ReadWriteMany]: only AccessModes [ReadWriteOnce ReadOnlyMany] are supported`. Is there another way to do this ? All the pods needs ReadWrite access to the PV.

Comment: If your native storage provider does not support ReadWriteMany then you can use nfs-server-provisioner to create an RWX access mode storage class for you. Check the process here. 
 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-readwritemany-rwx-persistent-volumes-with-nfs-on-digitalocean-kubernetes